# What's the use of tsumori in the first sentence and no in the second?

Tags: meaning, manga

> オレが...ここにいることで生かしてもらってることはわかってるつもりです
> Translation in the manga: I'm...here so I see you intend to let me live

tsumori means the person plans on keeping him alive? In another version it just says "I know being here keeps me alive."

> オレ自身が人類の天敵たりえる存在であることも
> Translation: I also see that I can be the natural enemy of humanity

In a different translation it doesn't say "also" but this sounds better, I think?

Comment: Hello Pam, welcome to the Japanese Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, [**we don't do translations or proofreading**](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799), so this thread (as currently written) will probably be closed. If there is a specific point that you would like help with, perhaps something specific in your translation that you want to double-check, please re-phrase your question to focus on that, and we can help you then.

Comment: Should really be two separate questions

Answer (score 1):

The [つもり](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82%E3%82%8A/#jn-148367) means not intentions (def #1) but something closer to:

> 実際はそうでないのに、そうなったと仮定した気持ち。「死んだ―で働きます」「親の―で世話する」

Essentially it is a way to weaken the preceding statement.

- Xとわかっています I understand X
- Xとわかっているつもりです I assume I understand X

The latter is implying *maybe I don't fully understand, but I think I see X*.

So the sentence in question: *I think I understand that I'm kept alive by being here,... and also that I could be the worst enemy of mankind*. The *also* corresponds to the last も. In that sense it would be more a more precise translation.

---

Just in case, directly answering the question of the title, the sentence has the structure 'Xことはわかっているつもりです. Yも.' The latter 'Yも' can be understood 'Yもわかっているつもりです'. Or the whole sentence is a variant of 'XもYもわかっているつもりです'.